# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/xml.so' after upgrade to php 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6

I upgraded my webserver from php 5.5 to php 5.6. When typing php -m, I get the following message:

```
php -m
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/xml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/xml.so: undefined symbol: _safe_emalloc_string in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/wddx.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/wddx.so: undefined symbol: php_XML_SetUserData in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mcrypt
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

I have a slave server with the same settings where this problem doesn't appear. I compared the size of the php binary and the size of all files in /usr/lib/php/20131226 between those two servers and they do match. So there is no obvious reason why it works on one server and not on another one.

I couldn't find litteraly anything on google regarding the "_safe_emalloc_string " error message
Does anyone has an idea where to look at to fix that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what flavor of linux are you using?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wddx.installation.php

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04. 

I installed php5.6-xml. The extension is available. The errormessage says "undefined symbol: _safe_emalloc_string in Unknown on line 0" which is not saying that the file is missing at all.

Comment: I managed to solve this by updating PHP 5.6: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and restarting PHP-FPM